# Proxy / ServiceBus / Reverse SSH

Tags: ssh, reverse-proxy, servicebus, appfabric

Trying to figure out the best way to easily connect a bunch of client machines running WCF service to a LAMP server on a wide area network....

Currently just set up set up each client with DynDNS, and port forwarding at the router... Absolutely not the best situation for deployment.

Ideally would like to have a simple program they run which automatically connects them to the LAMP server....

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Should I be looking at Reverse SSH, Windows Azure AppFabric ServiceBus?

Comment: Not programming-related - belongs on serverfault ?

Answer (score 1):

This is one the scenarios that Service Bus relay was created for. With the relay, a sort of tunnel is established via ServiceBus between your WCF services and your clients, independently of where each party is deployed (as long as both have internet access, that is).

This article has a tutorial on an scenario that's very similar to what you describe:
http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/tutorials/hybrid-solution/

Answer (score 0):

A reverse proxy would certainly be relevant here.

There are a number of ways to provide this. You mention using a LAMP stack so I'm assuming that you are using Apache as a web server.

You need a couple of optional Apache modules. Proxy and Reverse Proxy.

Typically you would assign a virtual "folder" to each actual app:

```
https://server/app1
https://server/app2
```

The reverse proxy would forward requests through to the actual, internal server/port:

```
https://server/app1  ->  http://localhost:8000/
https://server/app2  ->  http://localhost:8001/
```

(or whatever configuration you want)